# rails layout not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I upgraded one of my apps from rails to 2.3.2 from 2.0.2.  Start up find. However, once I start running any pages, the page will display but it doesn't seem to render any layout code.  None of the standard tag such head, body which are in the layout get render.  It seems that somehow layout is turned off.  I checked the error log and didn't find any complaint on layout.  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: same thing is happening to me

Comment: We really need more information before giving an answer to this.

Answer (score 7):

It could be that you have overrided initialize() in your controller so that the layout is ignored.

See:
[will initialize break the layout settings in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920748/will-initialize-break-the-layout-settings-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the layout explicityly? (For debugging only)

```
render :layout => "mylayout"
```

This may help you to find typos. A colleague once had a space after his layout name, "application.html.erb " which we found this way.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that and it works.  But it you take :layou=> 'mylayout" after render, it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Look if you have file `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` - it should be your default layout. I'm not sure but I think Rails in some version changed default layout file name and also, somewhere in the past, changed file extension.

Comment: yeah. and make sure your file extension is in right order. that was my problem once :) application.erb.html wasn't supported anymore after a certain release of Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure based on what you have provided, but a couple things you might check:

1. Do your layouts have the correct file extensions (.html.erb instead of .rhtml)
2. Does the layout name match the controller name or if not is the layout name declared inside the controller
3. I am assuming the layouts are in the correct directory in your application (app/views/layouts)

Best of luck

Comment: 1. yes
2. yes. it match.
3. yes

Answer (score 0):

I believe that somewhere between Rails 2.0 and 2.3 the location of `ApplicationController` changed from `app/controllers/application.rb` to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`. Is it possible that because of this (or some other reason) your `ApplicationController` isn't getting loaded properly? If so, and if you defined `layout` in that class, it might not be picking up the default layout.

Comment: When I've been gotten by this, the app won't start because application.rb defines ApplicationController instead of Application.

Answer (score 0):

Is it affecting all controllers?

If not look app/views/.html.erb which is probably very blank