# will initialize break the layout settings in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, initialization

In one of the controller, I need a specific layout. I added `layout` at the beginning. It works well.

But if I add an `initialize` function for some controller-based variable. Rails seems just ignore the `layout` command.

Is anyone have same problem? How can I fix it?

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController

  layout "layout_admins"

  def initialize
    @Title = "Admins"
  end

  def index
    ....... some code here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`initialize` is used internally to Rails to, well, initialize a new instance of your controller so it can then serve requests on it. By defining this method in this particular manner, **you are breaking Rails**.

There is a way through! A light at the end of the tunnel. A pot of gold at the end of the rainbow:

```
def initialize
  @title = "Admins"
  super
end
```

See that little `super` call there? That'll call the superclass's `initialize` method, doing exactly what Rails would do otherwise. Now that we've covered how to do it *your* way, let's cover how to do it the *"officially sanctioned" Rails way*:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_title


  # your actions go here

  private      
    def set_title
      @title = "Title"
    end
end
```

Yes, it's a little more code but it'll result in less frustration by others who gaze upon your code. This is the conventional way of doing it and I strongly encourage following conventions rather than doing "magic".

EDIT: If you're using Rails 5 then you'll need to use `before_action` instead of `before_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I don't mean to break Rails magic. >.< Seems I still have a long time before getting out from the tunnel...  :P

Comment: It's a Ruby behavior, not really a Rails issue. You're breaking Rails as a side effect of being built on top of Ruby, but initialize is a Ruby method. ;)

Comment: Calling super in an initializer is hardly magic - it's correct programming practice.  Still, your answer is the correct one

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure exactly how `layout` works its magic, but I'm willing to bet it's in a yield block in the ActionController#initialize method. So your overriding of initialize would explain the problem.

Looks like you have too options here:

1. Close out your new definition with super to call the ActionController initialize which should use the layout defined in the class.

   eg:

   ```
   def initialize
     @Title = "Admins"
     super
   end
   ```
2. Use a before filter to initialize your variables. This is the Rails Way of initializing values in a controller

   ```
   class AdminsController < ApplicationController
     layout "layout_admins"


     before_filter :set_title
     def set_title
       @Title = "Admins"
     end


     def index
       ....... some code here
     end
   end
   ```